# How to "save" GRUB configuration?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

My laptop with Ubuntu ran out of power. Before that incident I installed the latest updates, I cannot recall if new kernel was a part of the update (not sure it is important).

After that, it only boots to GRUB bootloader. I was able to find help here, so by using these commands:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

it boots to "unlock partition screen" and then to the proper system. Cool :)
The inconvenience is that, it boots to GRUB after ever restart/shutdown.

There is only one system installed, `ls` command in grub shell lists 4 partitions, 3 of them as reported as unknown file system, probably due to disc encryption.

Is there a way to "store" some info in GRUB so I will not be forced to execute these 4 command over and over every morning?

Comment: It sounds like the grub config is corrupted. One way is to `grub-install` command. Another is to run  `boot-repair`. Search this site for questions on these two topics. Then update your question if you need clarification. Note, the `grub-install` command will need specific arguments and options.

Comment: Try update-grub

Comment: The `sudo update-grub` only updates grub menu  with newest settings if changed. But will not fix most boot issues. A full grub install will reset all of grub's boot parameters, but if LVM & encrypted, you either have to do that from inside your working install, or be sure to mount & decrypt install. If you manually changed any grub settings or edited 40_custom, you will have to redo those change. And make sure all UUIDs in fstab are correct.